# Гугл Хром некорректно реагирует на js

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

В других браузерах форма отправляется. В Хроме просто зависает

```
$('#button2').click(function (eventObject) {
    $('span').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < $check_variables_array.length; i++) {

        if ($check_variables_array[i].val() == '') {
            eventObject.preventDefault();
            $check_variables_array[i].addClass('border').effect('pulsate', 'slow').after('<span id = "' + i + '"class=note> Обязательно для заполнения<span>');
            $('"#' + i + '"').effect('pulsate', 'slow');
        };
    }

    if ($('#add_message').length != 0) {
        if ($('#add_message').val().length < 7) {
            eventObject.preventDefault();

            $('#add_message').addClass('border').after('<span id = "5" class=note> Сообщение слишком короткое<span>').effect('pulsate', 'slow');
            $('#5').effect('pulsate', 'slow');
        }

        if ($('#add_phone').val() != '' && $('#add_street').val() != '' && $('#add_home').val() != '' && $('#add_title').val() != '' && $('#add_message').val().length > 7) {
            $('#button2').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('Отправляю...').css('cursor', 'wait').after('<p id = "wait" style = "width: auto; margin: 19px 0 0 10px; font: 11px Arial san-serif; color: #9CADAD;">Загрузка может занять некоторое время. Не закрывайте это окно.</p>');
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#add_phone').val() != '' && $('#add_street').val() != '' && $('#add_home').val() != '' && $('#add_title').val() != '') {
            $('#button2').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('Отправляю...').css('cursor', 'wait').after('<p id = "wait" style = "width: auto; margin: 19px 0 0 10px; font: 11px Arial san-serif; color: #9CADAD;">Загрузка может занять некоторое время. Не закрывайте это окно.</p>');
        }
    }

    setTimeout(second_passed, 35000);

});
```

Comment: Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:236
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect

Говорит консоль

Comment: У меня отправилась форма в Хроме. Посмотрите, там ерунда какая-то из цифр во всех полях :)

Comment: пришло. Получается проблема в каком-то расширении? С бобилных браузеров , кстати, тоже отправка не идет.

Comment: Консоль чиста. Ошибок нет. ПРоблема с js. Потому что когда его отключаю, форма идет. 
Подскажите плиз, как с этим справиться.

Comment: свойство кнопки disabled запрещает отправку формы.